# Why are my Typescript tests shown multiple times in VS Test Explorer using Chutzpah?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, chutzpah

I've gotten Chutzpah test detection working with my Typescript code in my ASP.NET Core project. After adding another test file though all the tests show up twice in the Test Explorer. Hovering shows that tests from one file are found in the other and vise-versa.

How do I stop all the duplicate tests from showing up?

Here is my chutzpah.json:

```
{
  "Framework": "jasmine",
  "Compile": {
    "Extensions": [ ".ts" ],
    "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [ ".d.ts" ],
    "Mode": "External",
    "UseSourceMaps": true
  },
  "References": [
    {
      "Includes": [
        "*/scripts/*.ts",
        "*/wwwroot/lib/xxxxxxxxxxxx.js",
        "*/wwwroot/lib/yyyyyyyyyyyy.js",
        "*/wwwroot/lib/zzzzzzzzzzzz.js",
      ],
      "Excludes": [ "*/scripts/*/*.d.ts" ]
    }
  ],
  "Tests": [
    {
      "Includes": [ "*/scripts/test/*.ts" ],
      "Excludes": [ "*/scripts/test/*.d.ts", "*/wwwroot/*" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

BTW you can see how I got testing working in the first place in [this blog post](http://kitsu.github.io/2016/06/22/unemployed-project-11/), and see the whole project [on Github](https://github.com/kitsu/JobLogger).

Comment: Note: this is using VS Community 2015 SP2 and Chutzpah 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

Your references section is too permissive and is including all your test code. See this [Chutzpah Issue](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/issues/293).

You need to change you references too:

```
  "References": [
    {
      "Includes": [
        "*/scripts/*.ts",
        "*/wwwroot/lib/xxxxxxxxxxx.js",
        "*/wwwroot/lib/yyyyyyyyyyy.js",
        "*/wwwroot/lib/zzzzzzzzzzz.js",
      ],
      "Excludes": [
        "*/scripts/*/*.d.ts",
        "*/scripts/test/*.ts" // <- Exclude test directory!
      ]
    }
  ],
```